# How to automate pagination into a for loop?

Tags: javascript, promise, request, axios

I'm making many API calls to iterate through pages of JSON data. I have this code that works, but I'd like to wrap it in a for loop, and be able to chain them together. Is it possible?

```
const URL = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/'

const params = {
    q: 'javascript',
    size: 10,
    subreddit: 'askreddit'

}
let ALL_UTC = []
// Submit First Request....
axios.get(URL + 'comment', {
        params
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // Handle First Response

        let length = response.data.data.length - 1;
        let utc = response.data.data[length].created_utc;
        ALL_UTC.push(utc)
        params.before = utc

        // Make A Second Get Request
        axios.get(URL + 'comment', {
                params
            })
            .then((response) => {

                let length = response.data.data.length - 1;
                let utc = response.data.data[length].created_utc;
                ALL_UTC.push(utc)
                params.before = utc

                // Make A Third Get Request
                axios.get(URL + 'comment', {
                        params
                    })
                    .then((response) => {

                        let length = response.data.data.length - 1;
                        let utc = response.data.data[length].created_utc;
                        ALL_UTC.push(utc)
                        params.before = utc



                        //Make A Fourth Get Request
                        axios.get(URL + 'comment', {
                                params
                            })
                            .then((response) => {

                                let length = response.data.data.length - 1;
                                let utc = response.data.data[length].created_utc;
                                ALL_UTC.push(utc)
                                params.before = utc

                                console.log(`finished all requests... \n${ALL_UTC}`)


                            })


                    })




            })
```

The output says the list is populating correctly with new dates:

> finished all requests...
> 1597903134,1597841977,1597664521,1597539246

As you can see this is getting old quick. I am new to JavaScript... How do I automate this into a loop?

Answer (score 1):

To chain them all together and write DRY code, consider using a recursive function instead:

```
const URL = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/'

const get = (params, pagesLeft) => {
  axios.get(URL + 'comment', { params })
    .then((response) => {
      let length = response.data.data.length - 1;
      let utc = response.data.data[length].created_utc;
      ALL_UTC.push(utc)
      params.before = utc;
      if (pagesLeft > 0) {
        get(params, pagesLeft - 1);
      } else {
        // FInished
      }
    });
};
get(params, 4);
```

Comment: I have been sitting here trying to figure this out ALL DAY! Thank you so much!

Comment: @CertainPerformance, ooh. Your response is a bit simpler than mine. I like it!

Answer (score 1):

It's less complicated than you think, but it requires thinking a little differently.

The cool thing about the Promise.prototype.then() method is that you can call it to return a new promise. Assign that to a variable, and repeat the assign-and-call on that assignment. I don't know what your termination condition would be, but how's about this:

```
//axios is already included
//url is already defined
//params is already defined
//ALL_UTC is already defined
//control_iterable is already defined

/* Generator function that accepts 1 promise and yields 1 promise on invokation*/
function step*(promisable) {
  while(true) {
    yield promisable.next(
      (response)=>{
        ALL_UTC.push(
          response.data.data[
            response.data.data.length-1
          ].created_utc
        );
        axios.get(
          url.append('comment'),{
            params,
          }
        //).catch(
        //  ()=>void(some terminating action, like promisable.cancel)
        );
      }
    );
  }
}

/*Use control_iterable and the step*() generator to get the tail-end promise,
 *and use its finally() method to write to the console upon completion 
 */
Array.from(control_iterable).reduce(
  (promising) => step(promising),
  new Promise((assume)=>assume())
).finally(
  ()=>console.log(`finished all requests... \n${ALL_UTC}`)
);
```

Obviously, there are some blanks for you to fill in. It feels a little abstract, and could be a homework assignment, I don't know. You didn't mention anything about your end conditions or how you're using it, so instead I gave you a really good start.

You could take what I've put, and use a generator function that yields in a for loop. You could translate what I put into a for loop, and just repeat the assignment of a mutable variable that holds each new promise. Again, I don't know how you know you're done, so I'm not quite sure what you'd need to do to that example.

You're already using Promises with axios, but if you're not familiar with generator functions, you can check out the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Forgive me if this comes off as condescending, but I'm trying to be a solid medium amount of helpful here, so if you haven't used the Array.prototype.reduce method, MDN is super helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

P.S. If I'm totally wrong about my "homework" guess, scold me for it in a comment, and I'll make this a bit more solid.